# Jenkins, Nightwatch console log japanese (unable to read, gabled text)

Tags: node.js, selenium, jenkins, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I use nightwatch on jenkins (windows) to make automation test. The jenkins [console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghVOy.png) do not show correct japanese. 
Also in command line, while running nightwatch the console log is not correct too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an environment variable in windows JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8. Restart jenkins, the console log in jenkins works correctly.
I don't know how the command line console log also work correctly now. 
Anyway thank you so much!